# Generating new SQLite database django

Tags: python, django, web

I had a duplicate sqlite database. I tried deleting the duplicate but instead deleted both. Is there a way I can generate a new database? The data was not especially important.

Comment: Surely you would just do the same thing as you did to create it manually, ie `manage.py migrate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) which can be used in order to reset the database.

then run

`python manage.py reset_db`

then

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: There is no use for `reset_db` as there is no database, `python manage.py migrate` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

When you have no database in your project, a simple `python manage.py migrate` will create a new db.sqlite3 file.